# rails route--undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I have a model called "newbie". The routes.rb file looks like:

```
  Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :newbies

  root to: 'static_pages#home'
  match '/about',   to: 'static_pages#about'
```

controller is like:

```
  class NewbiesController < ApplicationController

    def show
      @newbie = Newbie.find(params[:id])
    end
    ......
  end
```

When I write tests:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Newbie pages" do
  subject { page }
  describe "profile page" do
    let(:newbie) { FactoryGirl.create(:newbie) }
    before { visit newbie_path(newbie)}

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: newbie.name) }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: newbie.name) }
  end
end
```

It always fails says:

```
 1) Newbie pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit newbie_path(newbie)}
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `newbie_path' for #       <RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_2:0x007f97f7f33068>
 # ./spec/requests/newbie_pages_spec.rb:16:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

 2) Newbie pages profile page 
 Failure/Error: before { visit newbie_path(newbie)}
 NoMethodError:undefined method `newbie_path' for
```

I think resources:newbies will create helper methods like newbie_path, but why it says undefined method?

Thanks

Comment: Could u post all your routes . via rake routes

Comment: wow, problem solved. Looks like rails think newbies is plural of newby instead of newbie..... newby_path works...Thanks for the reminding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run 
    rake routes

The generated routes for newbies resource is totally different from the one you are expecting.

```
newbies GET    /newbies(.:format)
{:action=>"index", :controller=>"newbies"}
         POST   /newbies(.:format)
{:action=>"create", :controller=>"newbies"}

new_newby GET    /newbies/new(.:format)
{:action=>"new", :controller=>"newbies"}

 edit_newby GET    /newbies/:id/edit(.:format)
{:action=>"edit", :controller=>"newbies"}

newby GET    /newbies/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"show", :controller=>"newbies"}
 PUT    /newbies/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"update", :controller=>"newbies"}

DELETE /newbies/:id(.:format)
{:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"newbies"}
```

So you should use

```
newby_path(newbie)
```

Comment: yeah, just found out as well..Thanks